# How to cast vb6 byte array to Java Default Byte Array?

Tags: java, arrays, vb6

i'm making a program that will export a file with some data in byte array format.

But... i need to read this file trough a java program, and these two languages have different byte arrays format.

VB6 byte array have numbers like 0 to 255, but the java byte array can reach only the number 127.

Using the VB6, how can i cast this byte array to java standard?

Comment: Hint: you should first understand how the Java side will be using this data. You see; if the VB byte ranges from 0 to 255; and the Java byte ranges from -128 to 127 - maybe using the Java type "byte" is the wrong answer?! For example, if the VB bytes actually represent ASCII characters, then just forgetting about all values > 127 ... could be wrong?
In other words: understand how the data will be used; then decide if you want to use Java "byte" or "short" (for example; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html )

Comment: If you are reading binary from the file that consist of a binary bytes written to it, then the data will still be the same in memory in Java, only interpreted as signed. 
So the question is what are you doing with the byte array in Java? If you need to do arithmetic you should convert it to `int` as in chokdee's answer.

Comment: but... i cant change the java program. I need to do something in the vb6 side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use int instead of bytes.
Java byte is signed but you can convert it with the following code:

`public static int unsignedToBytes(byte by) {
    return by & 0xFF;
  }`